# compare one column in table with many columns in another table mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to compare a column in `tbl1` with more than columns in `tbl2`
to find the matched values my code with one column in `tbl2`

```
SELECT * FROM tbl1 WHERE new_pass1 IN(SELECT pass_no1 FROM tbl2)
```

this code compare with on column in the `tbl2` 
I want with more than column `pass_no2` and `pass_no3` in `tbl2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the other columns to your `SELECT`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl2 
WHERE new_pass1 IN(SELECT pass_no1 FROM tb2) OR
    new_pass1 IN(SELECT pass_no2 FROM tb2) OR
    new_pass1 IN(SELECT pass_no3 FROM tb2)
```

Comment: No worries I know that feeling!